# Why react is rendering the header from the screen but not the component?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm building the route stack for the screens for an app with expo, and since version 5 there's no more switch navigator, so i checked the documentation and i basically have to put all the screens in a ternary condition and it will make the switch.
Technally is making the switch through the condition but it is not rendering the component (but it renders the header)

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const isSignedIn = false

const PersonalAccessesStack = () => {
    <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="MyPersonalAccessesScreen"
    >
        <Stack.Screen
            name="MyPersonalAccessesScreen"
            component={MyPersonalAccesses}
            options={{headerShown: false}}    
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="ChangePasswordSystemScreen"
            component={ChangePasswordSystem}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="EnterPinScreen"
            component={EnterPin}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
}


const SpecialAccessesStack = () => {
    <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="MySpecialAccessesScreen"
    >
        <Stack.Screen
            name="MySpecialAccessesScreen"
            component={MySpecialAccesses}
            options={{headerShown: false}}    
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="UnlockSpecialUserScreen"
            component={UnlockSpecialUser}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="ChangePasswordSpecialUserScreen"
            component={ChangePasswordSpecialUser}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="RequestAccessScreen"
            component={RequestAccess}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="PasswordHistoryScreen"
            component={PasswordHistory}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
}


const TeamStack = () => {
    <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="MyTeamScreen"
    >
        <Stack.Screen
            name="MyTeamScreen"
            component={MyTeam}
            options={{headerShown: false}}    
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="ChangePinScreen"
            component={ChangePin}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="ChangePasswordScreen"
            component={ChangePassword}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="UnlockUserAccountScreen"
            component={UnlockUserAccount}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="TimeExtensionScreen"
            component={TimeExtension}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
}


const RequestStack = () => {
    <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="MyRequestsScreen"
    >
        <Stack.Screen
            name="MyRequestsScreen"
            component={MyRequests}
            options={{headerShown: false}}    
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="RequestFilterScreen"
            component={RequestFilter}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="SystemRequestScreen"
            component={SystemRequest}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="SpecialUserRequestScreen"
            component={SpecialUserRequest}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="TransferRequestScreen"
            component={TransferRequest}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="SharedFolderRequestScreen"
            component={SharedFolderRequest}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="SpecialUserAccessRequestScreen"
            component={SpecialUserAccessRequest}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="DependencyTransferRequestScreen"
            component={DependencyTransferRequest}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="PermissionRequestScreen"
            component={PermissionRequest}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
}

const DrawerStack = () => {
    <Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} 
        initialRouteName="Home" 
        drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props}/>}
    >
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Main}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="My Personal Accesses" component={PersonalAccessesStack}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="My Special Accesses" component={SpecialAccessesStack}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="My Team" component={TeamStack}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Requests" component={RequestStack}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Configuration" component={Configuration}/>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
}

const AuthenticationScreens = () => {
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
            name="LanguagePickerScreen"
            component={LanguagePicker}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="RegisterScreen"
            component={Register}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="ChooseCompanyScreen"
            component={ChooseCompany}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="RegisterManualScreen"
            component={RegisterManual}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="WaitForApprovalScreen"
            component={WaitForApproval}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />

    </Stack.Navigator>
}


function Root() {
    return (
        /* todo el return encerrado por un ternario si no se logueo (que renderice autenticacion)
        si está logueado al drawer */
        <>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator>
                    {isSignedIn ? 
                        <Stack.Screen
                            name="Drawer"
                            component={DrawerStack}
                        />
                    :
                        <Stack.Screen
                            name="Auth"
                            component={AuthenticationScreens}
                        />
                    
                    }
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
            
        </>
    )
}

export default Root;
```

[image: It enters in condition B]
[image: It enters in condition A]

I'm still fighting with this new approach of switching it looks simple but still it is not working for me, probably i put to much screens??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i could fix it this way:

App.js:
const isSignedIn = false

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    fontLoaded: false
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'icomoon': require('./assets/fonts/icomoon.ttf'),
    });
    this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      this.state.fontLoaded ? (
        <NavigationContainer>
          {isSignedIn ?
            <Root/> 
            :
            <Auth/>
          }
          </NavigationContainer>
      ) : null
    );
  }
}
```

Auth.js:

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function Auth() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
            name="LanguagePickerScreen"
            component={LanguagePicker}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
                name="RegisterScreen"
                component={Register}
                options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
                name="ChooseCompanyScreen"
                component={ChooseCompany}
                options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
                name="RegisterManualScreen"
                component={RegisterManual}
                options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
                name="WaitForApprovalScreen"
                component={WaitForApproval}
                options={{headerShown: false}}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}

export default Auth;
```

Drawer.js:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const PersonalAccessesStack = () => {
    <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="MyPersonalAccessesScreen"
    >
        <Stack.Screen
            name="MyPersonalAccessesScreen"
            component={MyPersonalAccesses}
            options={{headerShown: false}}    
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="ChangePasswordSystemScreen"
            component={ChangePasswordSystem}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="EnterPinScreen"
            component={EnterPin}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
}


const SpecialAccessesStack = () => {
    <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="MySpecialAccessesScreen"
    >
        <Stack.Screen
            name="MySpecialAccessesScreen"
            component={MySpecialAccesses}
            options={{headerShown: false}}    
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="UnlockSpecialUserScreen"
            component={UnlockSpecialUser}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="ChangePasswordSpecialUserScreen"
            component={ChangePasswordSpecialUser}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="RequestAccessScreen"
            component={RequestAccess}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="PasswordHistoryScreen"
            component={PasswordHistory}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
}


const TeamStack = () => {
    <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="MyTeamScreen"
    >
        <Stack.Screen
            name="MyTeamScreen"
            component={MyTeam}
            options={{headerShown: false}}    
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="ChangePinScreen"
            component={ChangePin}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="ChangePasswordScreen"
            component={ChangePassword}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="UnlockUserAccountScreen"
            component={UnlockUserAccount}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="TimeExtensionScreen"
            component={TimeExtension}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
}


const RequestStack = () => {
    <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="MyRequestsScreen"
    >
        <Stack.Screen
            name="MyRequestsScreen"
            component={MyRequests}
            options={{headerShown: false}}    
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="RequestFilterScreen"
            component={RequestFilter}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="SystemRequestScreen"
            component={SystemRequest}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="SpecialUserRequestScreen"
            component={SpecialUserRequest}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="TransferRequestScreen"
            component={TransferRequest}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="SharedFolderRequestScreen"
            component={SharedFolderRequest}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="SpecialUserAccessRequestScreen"
            component={SpecialUserAccessRequest}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="DependencyTransferRequestScreen"
            component={DependencyTransferRequest}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="PermissionRequestScreen"
            component={PermissionRequest}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
}

function Root() {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator 
            screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} 
            initialRouteName="Home" 
            drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props}/>}
        >
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Main}/>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications}/>
            <Drawer.Screen name="My Personal Accesses" component={PersonalAccessesStack}/>
            <Drawer.Screen name="My Special Accesses" component={SpecialAccessesStack}/>
            <Drawer.Screen name="My Team" component={TeamStack}/>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Requests" component={RequestStack}/>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Configuration" component={Configuration}/>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    )
}

export default Root;
```

It seems that it wants to read always a navigator at the component that you want to render the whole thing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).